# Flex Difference between AdvancedDatagrid and DataGrid? Are footer rows supported?

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

What is the difference between normal `DataGrid` and `AdvancedDatagrid`? Sorting, dragging columns, resizing columns are supported even in normal datagrid.

I want to add footer details like summery, average etc of each column. Does AdvancedDataGrid support these features?

Answer (score 2):

The AdvancedDataGrid control extends the capabilities of the standard DataGrid control to improve data visualization.

One of the most important aspects of the AdvancedDataGrid control is its support for the display of hierarchical and grouped data.

Hierarchical data is data already in a structure of parent and child data items. Grouped data is flat data with no inherent hierarchy. Before passing flat data to the AdvancedDataGrid control, you specify one or more data fields that are used to group the flat data into a hierarchy.

The Flex 3 DataGrid control supports footer rows, so I am sure that the AdvancedDataGrid control would be able to do the same.

[DataGrid footer example](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/03/flex_3_datagrid_footers.html)

Comment: +1 for information about hierarchical and grouped data.

Answer (score 1):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html

> The AdvancedDataGrid control expands on the functionality of the standard DataGrid control to add data visualization features to your Adobe Flex application. These features provide greater control of data display, data aggregation, and data formatting. The AdvancedDataGrid control is like a List control except that it can show more than one column of data, making it suited for showing objects with multiple properties.
>
> The AdvancedDataGrid control provides the following features:
>
> - Columns of different widths or identical fixed widths.
> - Columns that the user can resize at run time.
> - Columns that the user can reorder at run time.
> - Optional customizable column headers.
> - Ability to use a custom item renderer for any column to display data other than text.
> - Support for sorting the data by clicking on a column.

Answer (score 1):

ADG  = DG + some good features

1. With ADG you can group the data based on some grouping criteria
   but with DG you can't. Also there is concept of Grouped Columns and
   Grouped item renderers in ADG
2. With ADG you can display the
   hierarchical data.
3. ADG provides a multicolumn sorting which DG
   doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question for footer support: **footer rows are not supported**.

Here you can find the feature request for `DataGrid`: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-18563

You can find several solutions for this on the web, one useful solution is this: http://www.vanhulzenonline.nl/techblog/2011/02/21/footer-for-the-advanceddatagrid/